# Como hacer varias cuentas regresivas segun la cantidad de fechas que tenga guardas en mi tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, script

Tengo un formulario donde muestro datos ya guardados cuando guardo el primer registro la cuenta regresiva toma esa fecha y muestra el tiempo restante correctamente si guardo un segundo registro con otra fecha deberia de crearse otra cuenta regresiva con el tiempo restante de la nueva fecha pero no se crea, si no que la primer cuenta regresiva toma la nueva fecha (no se si es claro lo que digo) aqui tengo mi codigo para que vean no se en que parte del script pueda faltar algo o cual pueda ser el problema.

```
    <br>
    <div class="row table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Codigo Matriz</th>
                    <th>Codigo Equipo</th>
                    <th>Equipo</th>
                    <th>Modo Falla</th>
                    <th>Accion Preventiva</th>
                    <th>Gravedad</th>
                    <th>Frecuencia</th>
                    <th>Fecha del Periodo </th>
                    <th>Tiempo Restante</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()) 
                        {?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Id_matri']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Id_list']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Equipo']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Falla']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Accion']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Gravedad']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Frecuencia']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Tiempo']; ?></td>
                                <td><p id="demo"></p></td>
                                    <script>
                                        var fecha = '<?php echo $row['Tiempo']; ?>';

                                        // Captura la fecha del periodo introducido
                                        var cuenta = new Date(fecha);

                                        // Actualiza cada vez que va bajando 1 segundo
                                        var x = setInterval(function() {

                                            // Captura el dia y la hora actual
                                            var now = new Date().getTime();

                                            // Se resta el dia del periodo con el dia actual para hacer la cuenta regresiva
                                            var lapso = cuenta - now;

                                            // Calcula los dias, horas, minutos and segundos
                                            var dias = Math.floor(lapso / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                                            var horas = Math.floor((lapso % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                                            var minutos = Math.floor((lapso % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                                            var segundos = Math.floor((lapso % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                                            // Muestra el resultado en el elemento con id="demo"
                                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dias + "d " + horas + "h "
                                            + minutos + "m" + segundos + "s";

                                            // Una vez la cuenta llegue al dia del periodo imprimira el mensaje de tiempo expirado
                                            if (lapso < 0) 
                                            {
                                                clearInterval(x);
                                                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Tiempo Expirado";
                                            }
                                        }, 1000);
                                        </script>
                                <td><a href="edit.php?Id_matri=<?php echo $row['Id_matri']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Posponer</span></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola a simple vista veo que el error podria ser que dentro de tu while tienes un parrafo con id `demo` y cada vez que muestras el resultado de tu script siempre señalas a este, recuerda que los id son unicos. Una de la soluciones es que generes este id de forma dinamica y luego lo transfieras a tu script. Algo que me parece inecesario es que coloques tu script dentro del `while`. Mi recomendacion es que hagas una funcion y luego la llames pasandole los parametros correspondientes. aqui mi propuesta

```js
<script>
function cuentaRegresiva(fecha,fila){
 // Catura la fecha del periodo introducido
 var cuenta = new Date(fecha);

 // Actualiza cada vez que va bajando 1 segundo
 var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Captura el dia y la hora actual
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Se resta el dia del periodo con el dia actual para hacer la cuenta regresiva
  var lapso = cuenta - now;

  // Calcula los dias, horas, minutos and segundos
  var dias = Math.floor(lapso / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var horas = Math.floor((lapso % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutos = Math.floor((lapso % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var segundos = Math.floor((lapso % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Muestra el resultado en el elemento con id="demo"
  // EN ESTE CASO LE AGREGO EL PARAMETRO "fila" YA QUE EL ID "demo" SE GENERA DE FORMA DINAMICA
  document.getElementById("demo"+fila).innerHTML = dias + "d " + horas + "h "
  + minutos + "m" + segundos + "s";

  // Una vez la cuenta llegue al dia del periodo imprimira el mensaje de tiempo expirado
  if (lapso < 0) 
  {
   clearInterval(x);
   document.getElementById("demo"+fila).innerHTML = "Tiempo Expirado";
  }
 }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

**PHP+HTML**

```
 <?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()) 
      $demoid++ //esto es de ejemplo tu puedes generar el id="demo" de forma dinamica como mejor te p
      {?>
    <p id="demo<?echo $demoid;?>"><script>cuentaRegresiva('<?echo $row['Tiempo']; ?>',<?echo $demoid;?>)</script></p>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Probare a generar el id

Comment: Amigo he intentado de varias formas y he investigado un error que me aparece un error segun lo demas todo esta bien 

**Uncaught ReferenceError: cuentaRegresiva is not defined**

Comment: Ese error posiblemente sea porque no encuentra la función. Prueba poniéndola al principio de tu pagina porej: en tu Header. Esto por que?. Por que al momento de cargarse la pagina mas especifico de llegar a tu while esta llamando a la función cuentaRegresiva(); Eso quiere decir que tiene que estar previamente declarada.